# How to use Caliburn.Micro SimpleContainer in Data layer

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, caliburn.micro

Maybe it's a stupid question but I am stuck on it.

I am trying to use SimpleContainer as IoC in entire application, so in my data access layer I defined a bootstrapper in this way:

```
    public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase 
    {
        SimpleContainer container;

        public AppBootstrapper()
        {
            Start();
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            container = new SimpleContainer();
            container.PerRequest<IMyClass, MyClass>();
        }

        protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
        {
            var instance = container.GetInstance(service, key);
            if (instance != null)
                return instance;

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not locate any instances.");
        }
```

But how can I use it?

I simply want to get an implementation and try to write:

```
IMyClass mc = new IoC.GetInstance(IMyClass );
```

but I didn't find how

I've tried:

```
SimpleContainer container = new SimpleContainer();
IMyClass mc = new container.GetInstance(IMyClass,null);
```

and:

```
IMyClass mc = new IoC.GetInstance(IMyClass, null);
```

but none of them work.

What's wrong?

EDIT:

And, if i have one AppBootstrapper.cs for every project all work well or best practice are different?

Answer (score 10):

```
IMyClass mc = new IoC.GetInstance(IMyClass );
```

You can do it like this because `IoC` is a `static` class so you can't create new instances of it, instead you can do it like this:

```
IMyClass mc = IoC.Get<IMyClass>();
```

Nevertheless, this is not the recommended way too.

After you initialize your bootstrapper like that, and let's say you have a `SellViewModel` like this:

```
public class ShellViewModel {

    private IMyClass _mc;

    public ShellViewModel(IMyClass mc) {
        _mc = mc;
    }
}
```

Now when Caliburn.Micro tries to instantiate the `ShellViewModel` it will notice that the constructor accepts an instance of `IMyClass`, then it will create an instance of that class automatically for you and provide it to the `ShellViewModel`.

I really advise you to read about [Dependency Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), then read the documentation of the [`SimpleContainer`](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Simple%20IoC%20Container&referringTitle=Documentation) class, then read the article [Screens, Conductors and Composition](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2c%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation) to get a feeling for the whole process.

Comment: Iam using SimpleContainer in test of my domain model. i need to create a new empty object and try to set property value so i need the "new". When i write IMyClass mc = IoC.GetInstance<IMyClass>(); i get this error: "The field Caliburn.Micro.GetInstance cannot be used with type arguments"

Comment: I simply want to have IoC between all layer of my application and iam trying to do it only with Caliburn.Micro. If it's not possible i will migrate to ninject that allow it

Comment: @gt.guybrush Sorry about `IMyClass mc = IoC.GetInstance<IMyClass>();`, the method's name is actually `Get` not `GetInstance` so you can do it like this: `IoC.Get<IMyClass>()`, whenever you do that you will get a new instance if you registered the instance `PerRequest` and you can then set whatever properties you want. Also you can have `IoC` between all your layers but as I said it is not the recommended way.

Comment: `IoC.Get<IMyClass>()` works, thanks, ok i have used `PerRequest` so it's ok. Whats the recommended way to use it in test? Before i wrote `IMyClass mc = new MyClass(); then mc.Id=1;` but `MyClass mc = IoC.Get<IMyClass>()` seem better

Comment: @gt.guybrush Of course, if you are doing this for tests then it is OK and Yes `IoC.Get<IMyClass>()` is better than `IMyClass mc = new MyClass();`.

Comment: Little problem: i get 'IoC is not initialized.' while with `SimpleContainer container = new SimpleContainer();
IMyClass myClassExpected = (IMyClass)container.GetInstance(typeof(IMyClass), null);` all works

Comment: @gt.guybrush Don't forget to call `Start()` in the constructor of your bootstrapper, before calling this method you can't use `IoC`.

Comment: Ok, now i write: `AppBootstrapper ap = new AppBootstrapper();` but this call generate "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when `start()` is called in the constructor. My bootstrapper is a simply copy of the one in caliburn wikia

Comment: @gt.guybrush Don't create an instance of the bootstrapper your self, instead Caliburn.Micro will do that for you automatically when you add the bootstrapper to the resource section in the application XAML file. Check [this article](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Configuration%2c%20Actions%20and%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation) to see how this should be done properly.

Comment: iam doing it in my domain layer project, it's a class library: i don't have any app.xaml file

Comment: @gt.guybrush Caliburn.Micro shouldn't be used in the domain layer, it should be used for the presentation layer. Anyway I think you need to track this problem on your own from now on because I told you everything I know.

Comment: caliburn is for presentation but simpleContainer is a IoC and so should be used anywhere. using GetInstance works, even if it's less beautyful. Now i find this topic (http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/260738) but it's old and don't work for me

Comment: @gt.guybrush You are correct but `SimpleContainer` was developed to be a light-weight container to be used with Caliburn.Micro so you don't need a full fledged container in small projects. Anyway as I said I did my best to help you but you are on your own now because I can't track this any further.

Comment: no problem. thanks for your help. I learn something new tooday :)

Comment: @gt.guybrush You are welcome. Trying everything you learn over and over and in different scenarios gives you experience and you can find problems quicker.

Comment: After some month i return working on this project and change it, now i solved this problem using ninject module